# Upload iphone image with no extension (PHP)

Tags: php, ajax

In my php code I am processing an image uploaded from different source: desktop, mobile, etc. Normally, images come either as PNG or JPG, but I noticed that pictures taken from IOS/Iphone (android too maybe) come without an extension and as "image" only.
I have tried to reprocess the picture once uploaded to the server (with exif_imagetype and getExtension() to check if file is a picture and whether it as an extension, to be able to add one if missing according to its detected type. But I am failing to do since my script is only accepting PNG or JPG.
What would be the most effective and simplest way to solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    $uploadedFile = '';
    if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["type"]))
    {
        $valid_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $file_extension = end($temporary);
        if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") ||
         ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")) && in_array($file_extension, $valid_extensions))
        {
            $filetype=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = "upload/".$fileName;
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);      
            $newfilename = 'code' . '.' . end($temp);           
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Because the filename and its extension are supplied by the user, **this information cannot be trusted.** You should use something like [Fileinfo::mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) to verify that the supplied file is, in fact, an image before you attempt to treat it as one.

Answer (score -1):

Some images on IOS devices are heic [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format ], those are the life images.

So you are uploading something and when you check the extension and mime type the script skips and goes to the end, if you put an else statement you can let the user and know that the file they are submitting is not compatible.

```
if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") ||
         ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")) && in_array($file_extension, $valid_extensions))
        {
            $filetype=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = "upload/".$fileName;
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);      
            $newfilename = 'code' . '.' . end($temp);           
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename);

        }else{
            print "Invalid File Format :" . $_FILES["file"]["type"];

        }
```

Comment: Well the file is detected as jpg and adding the jpg extension it is perfectly readable! So it is not really of any use to skip iOS pictures since it is needed to have these uploaded as well!

Comment: Thanks for the not usefull vote, At the moment we do not have any class or support to edit heic images from php. Thats why I pointed that out.